# How to continue to drawRect: when finger on screen

Tags: ios, drawrect, uitouch

I have the current code:

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    self.objectPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    float x, y;
    if (self.objectPoint.x > self.objectPoint.x) {
        x = self.objectPoint.x + 1;
    }
    else x = self.objectPoint.x - 1;
    if (self.fingerPoint.y > self.objectPoint.y) {
        y = self.objectPoint.y + 1;
    }
    else y = self.minionPoint.y - 1;
    self.objectPoint = CGPointMake(x, y);

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

My problem is that I want to keep the object follow your finger until you take your finger off the screen. It will only follow if my finger is moving. `touchesEnded` only works when I take my finger off the screen, so that's not what I want either. How can I enable something that would solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to touch a part of the screen and you want to move the drawn object in that direction as long as you're holding your finger down, there are a couple of approaches.

On approach is the use of some form of timer, something that will repeatedly call a method while the user is holding their finger down on the screen (because, as you noted, you only get updates to `touchesMoved` when you move). While `NSTimer` is the most common timer that you'd encounter, in this case you'd want to use a specialized timer called a display link, a `CADisplayLink`, that fires off when screen updates can be performed. So, you would:

- In `touchesBegan`, capture where the user touched on the screen and start the `CADisplayLink`;
- In `touchesMoved`, you'd update the user's touch location (but only called if they moved their finger);
- In `touchesEnded`, you'd presumably stop the display link; and
- In your `CADisplayLink` handler, you'd update the location (and you'd need to know the speed with which you want it to move).

So, that would look like:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.velocity = 100.0;     // 100 points per second
    self.touchLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

    [self startDisplayLink];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.touchLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self stopDisplayLink];
}

- (void)startDisplayLink
{
    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleDisplayLink:)];
    self.lastTimestamp = CACurrentMediaTime();   // initialize the `lastTimestamp`
    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)stopDisplayLink
{
    [self.displayLink invalidate];
    self.displayLink = nil;
}

- (void)handleDisplayLink:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{
    // figure out the time elapsed, and reset the `lastTimestamp`

    CFTimeInterval currentTimestamp = CACurrentMediaTime();
    CFTimeInterval elapsed = currentTimestamp - self.lastTimestamp;
    self.lastTimestamp = currentTimestamp;

    // figure out distance to touch and distance we'd move on basis of velocity and elapsed time

    CGFloat distanceToTouch  = hypotf(self.touchLocation.y - self.objectPoint.y, self.touchLocation.x - self.objectPoint.x);
    CGFloat distanceWillMove = self.velocity * elapsed;

    // this does the calculation of the angle between the touch location and
    // the current `self.objectPoint`, and then updates `self.objectPoint` on
    // the basis of (a) the angle; and (b) the desired velocity.

    if (distanceToTouch == 0.0)                  // if we're already at touchLocation, then just quit
        return;
    if (distanceToTouch < distanceWillMove) {    // if the distance to move is less than the target, just move to touchLocation
        self.objectPoint = self.touchLocation;
    } else {                                     // otherwise, calculate where we're going to move to
        CGFloat angle = atan2f(self.touchLocation.y - self.objectPoint.y, self.touchLocation.x - self.objectPoint.x);
        self.objectPoint = CGPointMake(self.objectPoint.x + cosf(angle) * distanceWillMove,
                                       self.objectPoint.y + sinf(angle) * distanceWillMove);
    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

and to use that, you'd need a few properties defined:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat velocity;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint touchLocation;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;
@property (nonatomic) CFTimeInterval lastTimestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drag it with your finger, you want to:

- In `touchesBegan`, save the starting `locationInView` as well as the "original location" of the object being dragged;
- In `touchesMoved`, get the new `locationInView`, calculate the delta (the "translation") between that and the original `locationInView`, add that to the saved "original location" of the view, and use that to update the view.

That way, the object will track 100% with your finger as you're dragging it across the screen.

---

For example, you might:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.touchBeganLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    self.originalObjectPoint = self.objectPoint;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CGPoint translation = CGPointMake(location.x - self.touchBeganLocation.x, location.y - self.touchBeganLocation.y);
    self.objectPoint = CGPointMake(self.originalObjectPoint.x + translation.x, self.originalObjectPoint.y + translation.y);
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Probably needless to say, you need properties to keep track of these two new `CGPoint` values:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint originalObjectPoint;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint touchBeganLocation;
```

Frankly, I might use gesture recognizer, but that's an example of dragging with `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved`.